# Moving threads from forum to another

Tags: ee2, module, forum

There is no way to native movement of forum posts from board 1 to board 2. Has someone came up in any kind of solution for to do this?

I'm about to close one of my forums, and was wondering that do EE itself have now-a-days some tools to make that work, or is it possible to do via phpmyadmin or such?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a query on the database (you could use phpMyAdmin although a dedicated MySQL tool would be better), e.g.

```
UPDATE exp_forum_topics
SET board_id = X
WHERE board_id = y
```

You'd need to do the same for exp_forum_posts too.

Comment: ok, i need to look if i can come up with something, thanks.